# what happens to an SDL2 texture when the renderer changes?

Tags: delphi, sdl-2, delphi-10-seattle

The renderer changes when the window changes. As in a simple resize of the window. That's my assumption. I can be wrong.

I am asking this not about textures in general, but more specifically about textures which were created with two different SDL_TextureAccess flags - SDL_TextureAccess_Target and SDL_TextureAccess_Static. I am not using SDL_TextureAccess_Streaming so I have less interest in that one, but for completeness sake lets not forget that one too. Target-textures are created by me with SDL_CreateTexture, while Static-textures come from SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface.

The issue I am having is that upon resizing the window Target-textures dissapear and are not being rendered anymore until I call my update methods and recreate them, while Static-textures dont really care about that and keep getting rendered regardless.

I am not sure which behaviour is expected, since I started out only with Static-textures, the Target-textures dissapearing seemed anomalous for me, but chances are I've got that backwards and Static-textures are the anomaly or a "special" case.

Pasting code would hardly be of any use since there is really no issue with it... as far as I know. I am just interested in what is happening behind the curtains and what causes one to behave differently from the other whlist the renderer changes. And why one isnt affected by the renderer change? Can someone explain that to me in a not overly complicated and/or technical manner?

I am using Delphi, can't say I've had the chance to test this in c++ code.

**EDIT:**

I stand corrected, there is an error I dont understand: `CreateTexture() INVALIDCALL`

Just to be sure that it's not an error lurking somewhere in my program, I've written just a bare minimum new test program. And I can reproduce the error as easy as that...

Here's some code.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
TTF_Init;
window := SDL_CreateWindow('test', 100, 100, 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
renderer := SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
font := TTF_OpenFont(PAnsiChar('C:\arial.ttf'), 20);

new(color);
color.r := 255;
color.g := 255;
color.b := 255;
color.a := 255;
```

This works fine, no issues:

```
surface := TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, PAnsiChar('WTF!?'), color^);
texture := SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface)
```

then i just call this in my loop

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nil, nil);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

However as soon as I do this:

```
surface := TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, PAnsiChar('WTF!?'), color^);
texture := SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
target_texture := SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 50, 50);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, target_texture);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nil, nil);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, nil);
```

and same loop

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, target_texture, nil, nil);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Everything seems to be working fine too, until I resize the window, no more text rendered and SDL_GetError provides me with the error mentioned above.

Comment: If you didn't manually recreated renderer, it should remain the same. Documentation for SDL_DestroyRenderer says "destroy[s] the rendering context for a window and free associated textures.", so no texture should survive this operation. Is there any SDL error generated? Do you have the same results with different rendering backend (d3d, opengl)?

Comment: @keltar I am not destroying the renderer myself, the only place I do that is when quiting the program. SDL_error doesnt produce anything exactly at the moment I resize the window and the textures stop rendering. However it does throw me an Invalid texture error in another place - I would be inclined to think that's a separate issue, especially since, despite the error, calling Update brings back the textures. And I have not tried different rendering backends, since I couldnt get even opengl to work in delphi last time I tried, but I am also not interested in going with anything more advanced.

Comment: @keltar, just an update: Invalid texture error has been resolved, everything seems to be without errors for now, but my issue with target-texture remains.